# Finding a general solution(s) to a differential equation in first order form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

[image]

[image]

[image]

I cannot understand why we need $\alpha > 0$ ensure the continuity of $\ddot{q}$ at $q=0$.

Nor do I understand why to have $\dot{q}(0)=0$ we must have that $b >1$.

Furthermore I cannot understand you incorporate your initial conditions $q(0)=\dot{q}(0)=0$ into your solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see the images, what's written in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V(q)=0$ if $q\le0$, $V(q)=q^\alpha$ if $q>0$. $V$ is continuous at $q=0$ if and only if $\alpha>0$, since
$$
\lim_{q\to0^-}V(q)=0,\quad\lim_{q\to0^+}V(q)=\begin{cases}
0 & \alpha>0,\\
1 & \alpha=0,\\
\infty & \alpha<0.
\end{cases}
$$

If $q(t)=a\,t^b$ for $t\ge0$, then $q'(t)=a\,b\,t^{b-1}$. Then $q'(0)=0$ implies $b-1>0$.